# Statistical tests: how do (perception; actual results; and next) interact?

Tags: statistics, regression, probability, non-linear-regression, hypothesis-test

What is the interaction between `perception`, `outcome`, and `outlook`?

I've brought them into categorical variables to [potentially] simplify things.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

high, size = 100, 20
df = pd.DataFrame({'perception': np.random.randint(0, high, size),
                   'age': np.random.randint(0, high, size),
                   'smokes_cat': pd.Categorical(np.tile(['lots', 'little', 'not'],
                                                        size//3+1)[:size]),
                   'outcome': np.random.randint(0, high, size),
                   'outlook_cat': pd.Categorical(np.tile(['positive', 'neutral',
                                                          'negative'],
                                                          size//3+1)[:size])
                  })
df.insert(2, 'age_cat', pd.Categorical(pd.cut(df.age, range(0, high+5, size//2),
                                              right=False, labels=[
                                               "{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 9)
                                               for i in range(0, high, size//2)])))

def tierify(i):
    if i <= 25:
        return 'lowest'
    elif i <= 50:
        return 'low'
    elif i <= 75:
        return 'med'
    return 'high'

df.insert(1, 'perception_cat', df['perception'].map(tierify))
df.insert(6, 'outcome_cat', df['outcome'].map(tierify))

np.random.shuffle(df['smokes_cat'])
```

Run online: http://ideone.com/fftuSv or https://repl.it/repls/MicroLeftSequences

---

This is faked data but should present the idea. The individual have a perceived view `perception`, then they are presented with actual `outcome`, and from that can decide their `outlook`.

Using Python (pandas, or anything open-source really), **how do I show the probability**—and *p*-value—**of the interaction between these** 3 dependent **columns** (possibly using the `age`, `smokes_cat` as potential confounders)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use interaction plots for this particular purpose. This fits pretty well to your case. I would use such plot for your data. I've tried it for your dummy data generated in the question, and you can write your code like below. Think it as a pseudo-code though, you must tailor the code to your need.

In its simple form:

- If the lines in the plot have an intersection or likely to have for other values, then you may assume that there is an interaction effect.
- If the lines are parellel or not likely to have an intersection, then you assume there is no interaction effect.

Yet, for additional and deeper understanding, I placed some links that you can check out.

**Code**

```
... # The rest of the code in the question.

# Interaction plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.graphics.factorplots import interaction_plot

p = interaction_plot(
               x = df['perception'],
               trace=df['outlook_cat'],
               response= df['outcome']
     )
plt.savefig('./my_interaction_plot.png') # or plt.show()
```

You can find the documentation of `interaction_plot()` [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.factorplots.interaction_plot.html). Besides, I also suggest you run an ANOVA.

**Further reading**

You can check out these links:

- (A paper) titled [Interaction Effects in ANOVA](https://pages.uoregon.edu/stevensj/interaction.pdf).
- (A case) in practice [case](http://dwstockburger.com/Multibook/Mlt08.htm).
- (Another case) in practice [case](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interaction-effects/).

Answer (score 0):

One option is a **[Multinomial logit model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression)**:

```python
# Create one-hot encoded version of categorical variables
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc = LabelEncoder()
all_enc_df = pd.DataFrame({column: enc.fit_transform(df[column])
                           for column in ('perception_cat', 'age_cat',
                                          'smokes_cat', 'outlook_cat')})

# Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = (all_enc_df[['age_cat', 'smokes_cat', 'outlook_cat']],
        all_enc_df[['perception_cat']])

#clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs',
#                         multi_class='multinomial').fit(X, y)

import statsmodels.api as sm

mullogit = sm.MNLogit(y,X)
mulfit = mullogit.fit(method='bfgs', maxiter=100)

print(mulfit.summary())
```

https://repl.it/repls/MicroLeftSequences